# Understanding PHP Fatal TypeError "must be an instance of" doctrine symfony component project

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to lay the foundations for a report in OpenEMR.
I am new to Symfony and Doctrine
Since I am using Symfony components. It makes it a bit of a challenge to follow the tutorials because they all assume the full use of the Symfony framework and doctrine support. In my mind I don't have that. I have this method call to the ArSessionReposistory.

```
 public function getpaidata($payer_id)
{
    $row = $this->repository;
    return $row->getInsurerPaid($payer_id);
}
```

Inside the ArSessionReposistory the method that is being called is

```
public function getInsurerPaid(ArSession $payer_id)
{
    $insurerPaid = $this->_em->getRepository($this->_entityName)->findBy([
        "payer_id" => $payer_id
    ]);

    return $insurerPaid;
}
```

The error message is this:

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to OpenEMR\Repositories\ArSessionRepository::getInsurerPaid() must be an instance of OpenEMR\Entities\ArSession, integer given, called in C:\oerm_dev\www\dev\mindfulemr4\library\financialreports\src\FinancialSummaryByInsuranceController.php on line 72 and defined in C:\oerm_dev\www\dev\mindfulemr4\repositories\ArSessionRepository.php:26
```

I don't understand the relationship between the ArSessionRepository::getInsurerPaid() method call and ArSession which is where all the entities are listed with the getters and setters. I am hoping someone can explain "must be an instance of" error message.

Because what I am thinking now is the ->findBy(array) should be a method inside the ArSession even though I am trying to use the doctrine built-in findBy(array) method. The entire project code is located here

https://github.com/juggernautsei/symfony_twig_doctrine_component

**UPDATE:**

Nico Haase was right, it was really simple and not related to Doctrine or Symfony. Once I changed this

```
getInsurerPaid(ArSession $payer_id)
```

to this. I was trying to follow someone else code is why I placed that there.

```
getInsurerPaid($payer_id)
```

Everything worked like it was supposed to work. The error went away and the query completed. Check out the updated repo on Github.

Comment: This is pretty simple: why do you type-hint your parameter `$payer_id` with `ArSession` when you transmit an integer only? This error is not connected to Symfony or Doctrine in any way

Comment: My apologies for not grasping the simple. I thought I clearly said I was new to Symfony and Doctrine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**About your error**

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to OpenEMR\Repositories\ArSessionRepository::getInsurerPaid() must be an instance of OpenEMR\Entities\ArSession, integer given, called in C:\oerm_dev\www\dev\mindfulemr4\library\financialreports\src\FinancialSummaryByInsuranceController.php on line 72 and defined in C:\oerm_dev\www\dev\mindfulemr4\repositories\ArSessionRepository.php:26
```

This error is happening because your function `getInsurerPaid()` expects an `ArSession` object, but when you call it in your function `getpaidata()` you are passing an integer to it.

Instead, you should edit your `getInsurerPaid()` function to accept an integer parameter.

The method `getInsurerPaid()` is supposed to *return* an `ArSession` object from an id, you therefore don't have to ask to provide an `ArSession` object.

**About your repository method**

If you want to retrieve a single row from your repository, you should use the `findOneBy()` method, as it will return your object if founded, or otherwise `null`.

The `findBy()` method is useful if you want to retrieve *multiple* rows, and returns you an `array` of objects.

**Updated repository method**

```
public function getInsurerPaid(int $payer_id)
{
    return $this->_em->getRepository($this->_entityName)->findOneBy([
        "payer_id" => $payer_id
    ]);
}
```

**Some clarifications about Entities & Repositories**

> I don't understand the relationship between the ArSessionRepository::getInsurerPaid() method call and ArSession which is where all the entities are listed with the getters and setters.

**Entities** represents your models, those classes don't interact directly with your database.

The **Repositories** are the classes that interacts with your database. They are responsible of performing read/write operations to your database.

All your entity repositories inherits from the `Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository` class, and give you some methods to interact with your DB (eg. `findBy()`) so you don't need to rewrite it everytime you create an entity.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Now, I get the fact what repositories do. BTW changing it to  INT cause a new error. However, I will go back to the object advice and see how to create an object to send in there.

Comment: You're welcome. If you still getting some issues, don't hesitate to ask, we could maybe help you to fix it.

Comment: Manu, that would be great. I really would like some guidance. It is difficult learning in a vacuum. How can we work together?

Comment: Unfortunatly, i can't offer to help you directly, I was just suggesting that if you still had issues you can either post it in this answer's comments (if it's related to this specific problem), or ask another question. Cheers